# Not able to execute Shoes from command

Tags: ruby, shoes

I have installed shoes on my MAC BookPro and tried executing from the terminal and got the following error message.

jfleck-mbp:scripts_in_progress joe.fleck$ shoes just_for_fun.rb

-bash: shoes: command not found

Below you will find the installation of Shoes was successful and according to their instructions the 'shoes just_for_fun.rb' should execute the app.

Installation sudo gem install shoes Password: Fetching:
shoes-3.0.1.gem (100%) 
Successfully installed shoes-3.0.1 1 gem
installed Installing ri documentation for shoes-3.0.1...

Installing    RDoc documentation for shoes-3.0.1...

Here is my code:
require 'Shoes'

Shoes.app {

```
button("Trul?") {
        alert("Klapaucius!")
    }
}
```

So, I am new to this and not sure were to go from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Joe

Answer (score 6):

The shoes gem doesn't work and will probably never work. We are currently working on [shoes4](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4)- you can however try to use [green shoes](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes) - which is a shoes implementation, that works as a gem.

Or well you can try to download the installer from [shoesrb.com](http://www.shoesrb.com/) or you can try to [build your own pair of shoes](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/Building-Shoes) - since the installer is sadly broken with quite some OSX versions.

Shoes on!

edit: Wow that was a quick reputation gain so I put all the links that I additionally wanted to include. Thank you!

edit2: Just to be clear, it is totally on the road map to create a gem for shoes4 - which will work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Gems are libraries you can use in your Ruby scripts, which means you execute the script simply using `ruby just_for_fun.rb`.

Sadly, at this time, the *shoes* gem seems to be just a stub; I have just tried it and got this message:

```
Sorry, this gem currently does nothing. Team Shoes is working on Gemifying Shoes, and this is just a placeholder until then.
```

Try downloading the OS X installer from [the shoes web site](http://shoesrb.com); maybe that will work. (I tried installing it under Lion about a year ago, and couldn't get it to work; the windows version worked fine for me.)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is if the shoes program comes up normally without a ruby program specified. Try just running "shoes" in bash and if that doesn't work try "sudo shoes" since you installed the gem under root. You might need to install the gem under a normal user rather than root.

If neither of these work, try using the Shoes-3.1.0.run from https://github.com/shoes/shoes/downloads